# How to refresh a select list when another item is changed by a dynamic action?

Tags: ajax, plsql, oracle-apex

I am using Apex 4.2 and Oracle XE 11G.

I have a fairly complex page but have created a simplified version and imported it into apex.oracle.com and hope someone can suggest the problem.

Note the design may appear a little strange due to the parts i have removed but i think this should be possible.

The design is using the Mobile theme as it will be executed on either desktop or mobile and i was hoping to only need to build one.  Seems there are a few issues with the mobile theme when used on a desktop so might still have to build another GUI later but for now, am just using the mobile one for both desktop and mobile.

I have two elements on the page, an instance type and a version. These will eventually be hidden but are text fields to see what is going on.
I also have a region for each instance type containing a drop down list with the version of that instance.

If the instance is defined as the main version, there are certain restrictions on which other versions can be used. These relationships are defined in a table called `VERSION_LINKS`.
The other table holds the versions that the client has access to.

I have created a dynamic action such that changes to the main version will result in updating  `P1_PRIMARY_VERSION`.  This field is used in the real application for conditional display of combinations of instances.
This update works fine.

The problem is, that field is used in the SQL of the second SELECT LIST (`P1_RESTRICTED`) and so should then be updated to reflect the valid versions from `VERSION_LINKS` but instead, the field is just blanked when the `P1_VERSION` select list is changed.

I have created three ways to resolve this and the application on apex.oracle.com reflects all three.

- a) Use a refresh dynamic action on change of `P1_PRIMARY_VERSION` to    refresh `P1_RESTRICTED`
- b) Use a cascading LOV on `P1_RESTRICTED` with the parent item set to `P1_PRIMARY_VERSION`
- c) Use a set value dynamic action on change of `P1_PRIMARY_VERSION` to set value of `P1_RESTRICTED` to the SQL it already had.

None of these result in refreshing the list `P1_RESTRICTED`.

The SQL of `P1_RESTRICTED` is like this

```
select vc.version name, vc.version id
   from version_client vc, version_links vl
  where vl.name=:P1_PRIMARY_INSTANCE
    and vl.version=:P1_PRIMARY_VERSION
    and vl.certified_version= vc.version
    and vl.certified_with=vc.name
    and vc.client_id='DMO'
    and vc.name='TWO'
  order by vc.version desc;
```

and running this with the values as follows gives the right answers

```
select vc.version name, vc.version id
   from version_client vc, version_links vl
  where vl.name='ONE'
    and vl.version='1.0'
    and vl.certified_version= vc.version
    and vl.certified_with=vc.name
    and vc.client_id='DMO'
    and vc.name='TWO'
  order by vc.version desc;
```

displays 1.1.6 whilst

```
select vc.version name, vc.version id
   from version_client vc, version_links vl
  where vl.name='ONE'
    and vl.version='1.1'
    and vl.certified_version= vc.version
    and vl.certified_with=vc.name
    and vc.client_id='DMO'
    and vc.name='TWO'
  order by vc.version desc;
```

displays 1.1.7

My guess is it's something to do with session state i.e. even though the screen version is showing the `P1_PRIMARY_VERSION` changing, somehow it is losing the value which is resulting in blanking the second select list.

Any suggestions appreciated as to how to fix this. Thanks in advance
Trevor.

Workspace: TESTA
username: tester
password: tester
Application URL: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=35690:LOGIN_JQM_SMARTPHONE::::::
Developer URL:  https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex

Not this is not the same question as refreshing one apex list from another with ajax.  In that case the user is triggering the change and that works fine.

I am trying to have the user make a change in a list which then updates a text field using ajax and another ajax event on this text field should trigger refresh of the second list. There is a reason for doing it this way related to showing one of several regions on the page but using the same single text field to refresh all of them so just doing a straight refresh of one list from another doesnt resolve the issue in this case.  That might not be clear from the example on apex.oracle.com because i have tried to reduce it down to the minimum to show the issue. TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add both `P1_PRIMARY_INSTANCE` and `P1_PRIMARY_VERSION` to the list of items to submit under the cascading lov options. These drive your list, and they're only being changed on the page itself. Only submitting `P1_PRIMARY_INSTANCE` will mean that `P1_PRIMARY_VERSION` is still `NULL` when the query is executed, thus returning an empty list.
I changed your page 1 example to reflect this.

Comment: So looking at the changes you made, seems set the P1_RESTRICTED CASCADING LOV to be P1_PRIMARY_INSTANCE and the page items to submit to be P1_PRIMARY_INSTANCE, P1_PRIMARY_VERSION.  I'm having some difficulty because i'm using Apex 4.2 and dont like the new Apex 5 interface.  I think i've made the same changes on the real application but it doesnt seem to be working. Are there any other changes that you made to the original page 1 ?  Thanks

Comment: Thought i would reimport it back into my Apex 4.2 but seems they have changed the import format so i get an error that it's not a valid import file format. Also doesnt seem to be an option to export in 4.2 format even though it was a 4.2 application i originally imported into Apex 5 on apex.oracle.com.

Comment: @TrevorNorth You can indeed not import an apex 5 app to a 4.2 environment. Upon import on an apex 5 environment the application is "upgraded" (not really, it is inserted into the altered metadata tables and export will only work with the present state). And yes, I've set the items to submit on P1_RESTRICTED to those 2 items. What really helps is taking a look at the network traffic in the dev tools too, to see what happens or if errors occur. A drawback of using the mobile interface is no easy access to the developer toolbar really. Just for an exercise, you may want to try in desktop ui too.

Comment: Hi Tom, Yes i had also noticed that the developer toolbar doesnt show up in mobile - do they think you dont need to debug if you are developing for mobile ?  I was hoping to just develop once for mobile and the jquery moibile GUI looks quite pleasant on a desktop for the use I have but found there are a few issues - most recent one is that a multi value select list when changed and closed either by clicking on the page or clicking the X, logouts out of the app instead of returing to the page it is called on (when accessing on an ipad mini running ios8) but works fine on a desktop.

Comment: @TrevorNorth It would probably help you a lot to upgrade to apex 5 if you want to develop for mobile either way. The jqm version has a significant leap, which would hopefully mean a lot less bugs than with apex 4.2's two year old 1.2.1 version. Did you - by the way - resolve your issue?

Comment: I started developing my application in December (before 5 was out) and as the 0.1 release is almost ready for use, doesnt add value to change it now but will look at this for the next release.  Sometimes, you just have to go with what you have. Made the changes but on 4.2, still doesnt work on the real app, maybe something else causing a problem as i can see it works on the 5.0 version you fixed so have marked as correct answer.

Comment: @TrevorNorth if you have a sample ready to be imported in a 4.2 environment, you can send it to me or upload it as a static file in your sample app on apex.oracle.com. I have access to a 4.2 environment, I wouldn't mind taking a quick look.

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for the offer but i cant put the app on Apex.oracle.com as the database functions etc are proprietary code.  If you have a way to export the existing sample i uploaded into apex.oracle.com and get that to an Apex 4.2 environment that might be an option to see if the same solution works on 4.2

Comment: @TrevorNorth I understand - wasn't asking that :) I downloaded the imported app from the export repo and imported it in my 4.2.6 instance. And indeed, this doesn't work. In particular, the change event from primary_version which triggers a refresh causes a javascript error. Closer inspection reveals this as an error in jquery-mobile-1.2.1 somewhere. I'm not totally able to track this down, but it sure looks like a bug. Try this: enable debug by setting it to yes in the url which will load the full source. Then in console run: `$("#P1_RESTRICTED").trigger('apexrefresh')`. Inspect the stack.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a solution here. The refresh crashes on a select list. You may need to look into a workaround, try adding an updated jquery mobile version, or find some manual workaround. Damn ugly though. Strange how that is still in, looks rather common.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @Tom, i will see if i can update the jquery used and see if that helps.